# how to deal with dwg file

Tags: autocad, dwg

I want to use code to analyze dwg file. Any one know any SDK tools to start with?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.dwg):

*Autodesk sells a read/write library, called RealDWG, under selective licensing terms for use in non-competitive applications. Several companies have attempted to reverse engineer Autodesk's DWG format, and offer software libraries to read and write Autodesk DWG files. The most successful is Open Design Alliance, a non-profit consortium created in 1998 by a number of software developers (including competitors to Autodesk), released a read/write/view library called the OpenDWG Toolkit, which was based on the MarComp AUTODIRECT libraries. ODA has since rewritten and updated that code.*

Answer (score 2):

WoutWare's [cadlib](http://www.woutware.com/cadlib.html) supports WinForms embedding and a few other things.

Comment: And also .NET Core, so it works on Linux, too. (tested, is true)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any AutoCAD or compatible CADs, there are several OSS libraries that can handle DXF. ODA provides a free (unfortunately not open-sourced) tool [ODA File Converter](https://www.opendesign.com/guestfiles/oda_file_converter) that converts DWG to DXF. Notably, [ezdxf](https://ezdxf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/addons/odafc.html) has a wrapper API for the ODA converter.

```py
from ezdxf.addons import odafc

# Load a DWG file
doc = odafc.readfile('my.dwg')

# Use loaded document like any other ezdxf document
print(f'Document loaded as DXF version: {doc.dxfversion}.')
msp = doc.modelspace()
...

# Export document as DWG file for AutoCAD R2018
odafc.export_dwg(doc, 'my_R2018.dwg', version='R2018')
```

There is also [LibreCAD's module `libdxfrw`](https://github.com/LibreCAD/libdxfrw), but I haven't tried it.